# Do Java annotations add notation or functionality?

Tags: java, annotations

Are Java annotations used for adding functionality to Java code besides just adding documentation about what's going on in the code? What's the most advanced/complex functionality you could add to your code through an annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation are basically not more than a tag (with optional additional data) on a class/method/field. Other code (libraries or tools) can discover these tags and execute functionality dependant on the annotations found. I don't see a real limit on the complexity of the functionality possibly added by annotations. This can for example emulate AOP (adding functionality before or after a method with an annotation).

Answer (score 2):

Annotations as such only add information (metadata) to a class.

One can easily build a system that uses that metadata to provide additional functionality, however.

For example you can use `apt` to generate classes based on the information provided by the annotation.

Answer (score 2):

An annotation needs a tool to react to it. If such a tool does not exist the annotation is merely a notation. The "tool" can be an `APT` based agent or some piece of code that uses reflection (for instance, JUnit's `@Test`).

Several annotations are recognized by the Java compiler and thus have pre-defined semantics: `@Override`, `@Deprecated`, `@Target`.

Answer (score 1):

I would understand Annotations as a way to document your code in a machine readable way. 
For example in Hibernate you can specify the whole persistence information for your objects as annotations. This is directly readable for you and not in a distant xml file. But is also readable for the tool to generate configurations, database schemes etc.